# Anaconda prompt output gets stuck

Tags: machine-learning, keras, anaconda, windows-10, conda

I have a problem with anaconda prompt on windows 10 since the output of long running programs (Machine Learning with Keras) occasionally stops. Only when I press enter, the output seems to go on. I also assume that the program itself halts since the output does not seem to catch up fast.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem and has suggestions for me?

Thanks in Advance!